# "Dot" plot with pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to use pgfplots to create a simple "dot" plot, which I can make rather easily with KaleidaGraph (example below).  I know there are alternative visualization such as histograms but that's not what I want.

The dataset is a single column of values.  I have taken a look at the pgfplot documentation but I'm unsure how to get such a plot, so if anyone can point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Edit: here's my attempt to make it work, perhaps there's a mistake somewhere:

```
\documentclass[english,letter,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}    

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title = title
]
\addplot[scatter, only marks] 
table {
y  
10  
10  
12  
13  
16  
20  
22  
8   
13  
15  
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\addplot[scatter,only marks]` ?

Comment: @percusse this did not work.

Comment: You need both an x-value and a y-value; see my answer below.  Plus table is, I think, for reading from a file.  Use coordinates if you want to enter things the way you are (but you still need both an x and a y).

Answer (score 3):

[image]Presumably you have two columns, one for the x-values and one for the y-values.  See below.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mydata.dat}
1 3
2 4
2 5
1 3
3 2
4 1
5 4
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[only marks] table[x index=0, y index=1] {mydata.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As an aside, Ed Tufte would suggest you do away with the right and top axes to maximize the content to ink ratio for readability.

Comment: the data is only one column, with possible repeated values.  Perhaps I did not give enough context, the "dot" plot is meant to show the distribution of values, so there is no "x" data.

Comment: So how's the x-coordinate determined?  Randomization?  As an aside, this kind of information is usually and more clearly represented by a bar graph or histogram.

Comment: I don't know how KaleidaGraph does it but yes, I suppose it is some type of random number generator for when the y-value is non-unique.  I am aware of the option to go with histograms but I was hopeful that the "dot" plot could be done with pgfplot.